# FPCR.FIZ=1: for which floating-point instructions inputs are not flushed to zero?

Tags: floating-point, arm, denormal-numbers, subnormal-numbers

Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture (issue I.a) (emphasis added):

> FIZ, bit [0]
>
> When FEAT_AFP is implemented:
>
> 0b1 Denormalized single-precision and double-precision inputs to **most** floating-point
> instructions flushed to zero.

A simple question: for which floating-point instructions inputs are *not* flushed to zero under `FIZ=1`?

Comment: It says right below: "For more information, see Flushing denormalized numbers to zero on page A1-58 and the
pseudocode of the floating-point instructions."  That section gives a complete explanation.  As in your other question, and for the same reasons, the principal exceptions are FNEG, FABS, FMIN, FMAX.

Comment: Thanks! I've overlooked the "For more information, see ...".

Comment: As for the _inputs_ I see that the exceptions are FABS and FNEG, but not FMIN / FMAX.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  FMAX/FMIN have the behavior that *outputs* are not flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A simple question: for which floating-point instructions inputs are not flushed to zero under `FIZ=1`?

FNEG, FABS.